# Set Environment Variable from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have an environment variable like

```
ABC_XYZ=false
```

When I `echo $ABC_XYZ`
It gives me `false`
Now I am inside a script I do these steps

```
>echo $ABC_XYZ 
false
>ABC_XYZ=true
>echo $ABC_XYZ
true
```

Now after exiting from the script 
`echo $ABC_XYZ` again gives me `false`
Any way through which i can set the value as true from inside the script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to run the script in the shell's current context using `source`.

Assuming your script is in your current directory:

```
$ source ./script_filename
```

or

```
$ . ./script_filename
```

Quoting from `help source`:

> source: source filename [arguments]
>       Execute commands from a file in the current shell.
>
> ```
> Read and execute commands from FILENAME in the current shell.  The
> entries in $PATH are used to find the directory containing FILENAME.
> If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters
> when FILENAME is executed.
> ```

---

To make the variable available in subsequently forked child processes(either shell or any other process), you'll need to export the environment variable like this in the script:

```
export ABC_XYZ
```

Comment: Added source ~/.bash_profile
and export ABC_XYZ still no success

Comment: `source script` must be written on the command line and not inside the script

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the below script file with this:

```
source ./export.bash
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12542101)

Comment: okay thanks for advice.i will do from next time. I am too new to stack overflow.